# Using TortoiseGit to affect on a remote repository via rebase-squash

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, tortoisegit, git-squash

As the title suggests

I am trying to squash the last two commits into one

https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test

and register that into the Github remote repo, though it only makes the changes locally, without committing them..

I am doing this via the log window. Right click on B then "Rebase master onto this ..."

After the process I expect the remote repo to be "A, BCD" rather than the local repo on my PC.

How should I do that via TortoiseGIT. I am working under Windows with Client:

```
TortoiseGit 1.8.16.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin) 
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

This metrod requires GIT bash:

```
1) Save a local copy of the repo you want to squash
2) Copy the hash of the commit where you want the head to be <NEW_HEAD_COMMIT_HASH> ( for example bf426ff4a0506dae418d09c8b1551fec071e5d84 )
3) Re-base using "git push origin +<NEW_HEAD_COMMIT_HASH>:master"
( for example "git push origin +bf426ff4a0506dae418d09c8b1551fec071e5d84:master" without the quotes )
4) Save a local copy of the re-based repo from 3)
5) Add the modifications from repo 1) to the one you've saved 4)
6) Commit the changes, add one big general log. Done!
```